# Appending semicolon to each item in array and comma to set of array objects, to form a string

Tags: java, arrays, gson

1. I have a JSON array like `{"payment":[{"a":"11","b":"21","c":"34","d":"0"},{"a":"54","b":"66","c":"21","d":"76"},{"a":"34","b":"23","c":"43","d":"88"}]}`
   and I have iterated each item in the array to form a string.
2. I'm trying to discard the array object where "d" equals 0 (zero) in array. Ex: `{"a":"11","b":"21","c":"34","d":"0"}`.
3. I added a semicolon between each item and a comma to each array object: `{54;66;21;76,34;23;43;88}`.
4. But I need a final result like this: `{"payment":"54;66;21;76,34;23;43;88"}`.

Code:

```
public class TestJson {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonArray = "{\"payments\":[{\"a\":\"11\",\"b\":\"21\",\"c\":\"34\",\"d\":\"0\"},{\"a\":\"54\",\"b\":\"66\",\"c\":\"21\",\"d\":\"76\"},{\"a\":\"34\",\"b\":\"23\",\"c\":\"43\",\"d\":\"88\"}]}";
    JsonObject jsonObject2 = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, JsonObject.class);

    String key = "";
    JsonObject innerObj = new JsonObject();
    StringBuilder joinBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    JsonArray paymentsArray = jsonObject2.getAsJsonArray("payments");

    for (JsonElement jsonElement : paymentsArray) {
        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> elemEntry = ((JsonObject) jsonElement).entrySet();
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonElement>> itr = elemEntry.iterator();
        String finalVal = "";
        String semiColon = "";
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = itr.next();
            key = entry.getKey();
            JsonPrimitive valuePrim = entry.getValue().getAsJsonPrimitive();
            if (valuePrim.isString()) {
                finalVal = valuePrim.getAsString();
            }
            joinBuilder.append(semiColon).append(finalVal);
            semiColon = ";";
        }
        joinBuilder.append(",");
    }
    innerObj.addProperty("payments", joinBuilder.toString());
    System.out.println(innerObj.toString());
}}
```

Output: `{"payments":"11;21;34;0,54;66;21;76,34;23;43;88,"}`

But I need to remove a comma at the end of the string, and if "d" field has 0 then to discard whole array object. Ex: `{11;21;34;0}`

Comment: Great requirements

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Good luck! We won't code that for you.

Comment: This is my first post in stackoverflow. I will improve my post and added sample code what i have tried. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonArray = "{\"payments\":[{\"a\":\"11\",\"b\":\"21\",\"c\":\"34\",\"d\":\"0\"},{\"a\":\"54\",\"b\":\"66\",\"c\":\"21\",\"d\":\"76\"},{\"a\":\"34\",\"b\":\"23\",\"c\":\"43\",\"d\":\"88\"}]}";
    JsonObject jsonObject2 = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, JsonObject.class);
    JsonObject innerObj = new JsonObject();
    StringBuilder joinBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Map<String, String> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    JsonArray paymentsArray = jsonObject2.getAsJsonArray("payments");
    for (JsonElement jsonElement : paymentsArray) {
        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> elemEntry = ((JsonObject) jsonElement).entrySet();
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonElement>> itr = elemEntry.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = itr.next();
            testMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getAsString());
        }
        if (testMap.get("d").equals("0")) {
            testMap.clear();
        } else {
            joinBuilder.append(StringUtils.join(testMap.values(), ';')).append(",");
        }
    }
    joinBuilder.deleteCharAt(joinBuilder.length() - 1);
    innerObj.addProperty("payments", joinBuilder.toString());
    System.out.println(innerObj.toString());
}
```

Output: `{"payments":"54;66;21;76,34;23;43;88"}`